# Why not make axios calls in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, axios

It's common knowledge that you should make api calls in your componentDidMount to grab data for a React component if you need that data on load. My question that I haven't been able to find a real solid answer for is why not use the constructor to make the api call? I'm not trying to do that, its more just a curiosity as to exactly why you shouldn't do that. The .then would still have the correct value of this if the callback was bound or was an arrow function and it seems that the request would be initiated that much sooner (probably milliseconds) but still.

Comment: Is there any way to change what a constructor returns? Without being able to change what a constructor returns how would code external to the constructor ever know that the asynchronous code had completed?

Comment: You would create a closure and the .then would handle the response with the value of this still referring to the new instance of the component. Also, you can change what a constructor returns although the default is to return the newly created object.

Comment: I'll rephrase; you write a unit test that expects the constructed object to be fully initialized when the constructor completes, your closure is still sitting there waiting for a response & your unit test keeps on running reporting a failure. Only your closure knows that the promise is not yet fulfilled.

Comment: I see what you're getting at but I'm still confused how that's a reason to not do it. In that example, the constructor still returns while the http request is traveling. The initial values set up in the constructor would be on the object. What's the different between the unit test checking the constructor while waiting for componentDidMount to receive a response and setState?

Comment: I've always seen that as a good enough reason; something will mutate state in the future after your calling code has taken over ownership of the instance.

Comment: Imagine your calling code is wrapping the new instance in a proxy with a set trap. The closure in the constructor will still be referencing the non-proxied instance. The promise resolves & sets a property on the instance & the proxied object in your calling code never hits the set trap.

Comment: Why don't use the constructor to make more than initializing stuff? technically you can, but is considered a bad approach because the constructor blocks the render, you can't render until the constructor finish (and some other methods were called), so the principal issue is to avoid anything that can't delay a render, your react component should be able to be visible with and without the data that you want to reach. That's why this kind of executions are delegate to the `didMount`, because they execute after the render process.

Comment: Another thing is the separation of responsibilities, why keep that in the constructor?the constructor should be used to create and set the principals things that concern to that component(state, refs, etc),otherwise, you will have a big constructor with a lot of responsibilities that don't really belong to the construction process. Anyway is not an obligation or a rule, but is a good practice to make better UIs and frontend code.Keep in mind that most of the patterns of React are used to improve the quality of the code and the ability to reuse, extend or improve with the lest changes posible

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the responses.  The proxy and set trap is unfamiliar to me so it's hard for me to comment on that. As far as the render being blocked that's actually not the case. Tested yesterday on a simple react app making calls to the swapi api. The render still gets called with the instantiated object while the promise is waiting to be fulfilled. But I do agree with you on the separation of concerns. All interesting feedback. Again, not trying to actually do this. My brain just comes up with random questions like this sometimes.